# Choosing content of cache in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, ads

I am making a web application with updates and content listing with PHP ad codes included in it.
How can I disable caching only for PHP ad codes?

Comment: Unfortunately, CodeIgniter output caching, caches whole of the page. It works per-page basis. If you want to cache sections on a page separately, take a look at [Caching Driver](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html) and give it a try.

Comment: You can try the smart cache library at https://github.com/msnisha/smart-cache where you can have dynamic view or session variables in cahced views. In view if you put <--session:variableName--> then the value is replaced with session variable and same for views also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After Searching a lot for this problem i found this**

[Simple Cache](http://jimdoescode.blogspot.in/2011/01/codeigniter-and-caching-love-hate.html)

This really worked like a charm, if anyone who got the same problem may use it :)